# how to save xlsx (office 2007) file as XML file format

Tags: xml, xsd, xlsx

I am trying to save office 2007 xlsx file to xml file format so that i can read it programmatically.

While saving xlsx file as xml it gives error "Cannot save XML data bcoz workbook doesnt content XML mapping."

I have found that I need to add XML mapping first and then It is possible. On Office 2007 site they have mentioned that first import xsd file for XML mapping and then it can be saved as XML file format.

So Please anyone tell me how to create xsd file from xlsx file.

Also tell me what could be done to save file as xml file other than this approach.

Note: I could not use any external tool to convert xlsx to xml because User have to create file xml file using "save as".

I was using Convert xls of softinterface which convert xlsx file to xml office 2007 format. But this software is can work on windows only.  My server is Linux.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is probably to instruct your users to save it in the "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format. That XML format is easy to understand and straightforward for further processing.

With that format, you don't need not XML mapping, no schema file etc.

Comment: Problem is that we are using xlsx is that our xlsx file can have huge no. of rows and columns which is very less in xls office 2003 format.

Comment: I'm not recommending XLS Office 2003 format but the less often used _XML Spreadsheet 2003_ format. (It's about the twelfth format from the top in the Save As dialog.) It doesn't have the limitations of Office 2003 regarding the number of rows and columns.